# Post multidimensional array HTML form

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I try to get a PHP array like this

```
array(
    color => array("blue", "red", "yellow", "pink"),
    size => array("small", "medium, "large"),
    width => array("30", "32, "34"),
);
```

The data is posted from a HTML form like below

```
<form method="post" action="post.php">
    <input type="text" name="data[color][]" value="red"/>
    <input type="text" name="data[color][]" value="blue"/>
    <input type="text" name="data[size][]" value="small"/>
    <input type="text" name="data[width][]" value="30"/>
    <input type="text" name="data[width][]" value="32"/>
</form>
```

The problem is that only the last items are posted in the array.
The output from the array is

```
array(
    color => array("blue"),
    size => array("small"),
    width => array("32"),
);
```

Is there something missing in my form why this is happening?

Comment: Have your tried 'print_r($_POST)'?   It should work: 'echo $_POST["data"]["color"][0]' should show 'red'.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you then add 'post.php' code to your question above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure what you want but how about this:

```
foreach($_POST["data"] as $row => $data)
{
 echo("$row = " . implode(", ", $data) . PHP_EOL);
}
```

Will produce:

```
color = red, blue
size = small
width = 30, 32
```

OR

Just JSON encode the $_POST array.  That converts the array to a string.  Later you can JSON decode it to turn it back into an array.

Answer (score 0):

You are not submitting your POST add an submit button - Try this for example:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="data[color][]" value="red"/>
    <input type="text" name="data[color][]" value="blue"/>
    <input type="text" name="data[size][]" value="small"/>
    <input type="text" name="data[width][]" value="30"/>
    <input type="text" name="data[width][]" value="32"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST); // this will only print a filled array once submit is clicked.
```

You'll see this if submit wasn't clicked:

```
Array
(
)
```

And this if it was :

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [color] => Array
                (
                    [0] => red
                    [1] => blue
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => small
                )

            [width] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 30
                    [1] => 32
                )

        )

)
```

On your post.php file - You might be printing a different array altogether because without submitting the form this data stays in the input line....  you should print : $_POST; there like in the example.

How are you even reaching there without a submit button is beyond me ...:)

Comment: Thanks @Shlomtzion well I use Wordpress and I want save this data into a meta_value. The submit button is handled by Wordpress self